# Apache Flink consecutive splits strange behaviour

Tags: java, apache-flink

I believe, that Flink behaves oddly when two splits are done consecutively. I might have some mistakes in my implementation logic that's why I post here to ask your opinion.

Minimum example: I have a text file containing the words Apple, Banana and Orange. I pass this in stream execution environment as source. I do a first split, in which the select condition is if the argument is the word "Apple". If yes, I put it the "topic" *Apples*, otherwise in the "topic" *NotApples*. I then select on this split stream the "topic" *NotApples* and I split it again but this time the condition checks if the argument is the word "Orange". If yes, it is placed in the "topic" *Oranges*, otherwise in the "topic" *NotOranges*.

What I expect at the end, when I print the last split stream's topic *NotOranges* is to have only the word "Banana" printed. However, what I actually have printed is both the words "Apple" and "Banana". I noticed that when a second split is done, the stream that it is processed is not the one that contains only the elements of the topic which I selected from (i.e., NotApples) but all the elements. Am I missing something?

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataStream<String> datastream = env.readTextFile("input.txt");
SplitStream<String> splitStream1 = datastream.split(new OutputSelector<String>() {

    @Override
    public Iterable<String> select(String arg0) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (arg0.equals("Apple")) {
            output.add("Apples");
        } else {
            output.add("NotApples");
        }
        return output;
    }
});


DataStream<String> notApplesStream = splitStream1.select("NotApples");
SplitStream<String> splitStream2 = notApplesStream.split(new OutputSelector<String>() {

    @Override
    public Iterable<String> select(String arg0) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (arg0.equals("Orange")) {
            output.add("Oranges");
        } else {
            output.add("NotOranges");
        }
        return output;
    }
});

DataStream<String> notApplesAndNotOrangesStream = splitStream2.select("NotOranges");
notApplesAndNotOrangesStream.print();
env.execute("SplitTest");
```

Output:

```
1> Apple
1> Apple
1> Banana
2> Apple
2> Apple
2> Apple
4> Apple
4> Apple
4> Banana
3> Apple
3> Banana
3> Apple
```

*NB.: I know that I could have a single split to implement the same logic (in which I check if the argument is "Apple" OR "Organge"). However, this is not the point of my question. I initially noticed this behaviour in a more complicated program I've written where two consequetive splits are necessary so I decided to try to recreate it in a minimal example to check if I can reproduce it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a recent discussion about this incorrect behavior on the mailing list, with the subject "About Deprecating split/select for DataStream API". I think the key comment was:

> First, we must admit that the current implementation for split/select
>   is flawed. I roughly went through the source codes, the problem may be that
>   for consecutive select/split(s), the former one will be overridden by the
>   later one during StreamGraph generation phase. That's why we forbid this
>   consecutive logic in FLINK-11084.

After looking at [FLINK-11084](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11084) and the resulting patch, I believe recent releases of Flink will throw an exception if you do two consecutive split/selects.

Answer (score 0):

Given what I know about how Split/Select is implemented, it wouldn't surprise me if this doesn't work (though I don't know enough to be sure). Moreover, split/select has recently been deprecated (though it's not clear if it will actually go away).

The better way to do split/select is via [side outputs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/side_output.html). This is a more powerful mechanism with a cleaner implementation.

Comment: David, thanks for the answer and suggestion. Any chance to ask your colleagues at Ververica to give us an explanation on why split is implemented this way? I was expecting .select(tag) to return a DataStream that only includes the elements belonging to this tag and not all the elements in the initial stream (if that's the case).

Comment: Split/Select isn't an operator. It's more of a declaration of what to pass along, and the second select is overriding the first one.